# Microsoft SQL Query‏ return repeated rows in one row

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamics-crm

I need your help for this query:

```
SELECT        
    'ABBOTT' AS Customername, 'DaleelMAMA' AS AccountName, 
    dbo.AccountBase.Name AS FullName, 
    dbo.AccountBase.Telephone1 AS  MobilePhone, 
    dbo.AccountBase.new_HomePhone1 AS HomePhone, 
    dbo.new_otherparentinformationBase.new_MobilePhone AS ParentPhone, 
    dbo.AccountBase.new_preferredlanguagetext AS Language
FROM            
    dbo.AccountBase 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.new_otherparentinformationBase ON dbo.AccountBase.AccountId = 
        dbo.new_otherparentinformationBase.new_MotherName_lookup
```

This query returns this result set:

The original result

```
ABBOTT  DaleelMAMA  Eman    55555555    NULL    56545412    Arabic
ABBOTT  DaleelMAMA  Eman    55555555    NULL    22222222    Arabic
ABBOTT  DaleelMAMA  Eman    55555555    NULL    25456552    Arabic
ABBOTT  DaleelMAMA  Hala    55552504    22252128    NULL    Arabic
```

but I need to update my query to return this result but as below, if u see u will find that Eman row repeated three time and this because its include different parent phone numbers, so i need to make this result in one row include the mother number and its related parent phones numbers.

required result

[image: required result]

please see above link for required result that aim looking about it,  thanks for your support in advance.

whole solution look

[image: whole solution look]

Comment: Whether a user can have more than 4 phones numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it always 4 `ParentPhone` per `Name` then try something like this

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT        
    'ABBOTT' AS Customername, 
    'DaleelMAMA' AS AccountName, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by dbo.AccountBase.Name order by dbo.AccountBase.Telephone1) as rn,
    dbo.AccountBase.Name AS FullName, 
    dbo.AccountBase.Telephone1 AS  MobilePhone, 
    dbo.AccountBase.new_HomePhone1 AS HomePhone, 
    dbo.new_otherparentinformationBase.new_MobilePhone AS ParentPhone, 
    dbo.AccountBase.new_preferredlanguagetext AS Language
FROM            
    dbo.AccountBase 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.new_otherparentinformationBase ON dbo.AccountBase.AccountId = dbo.new_otherparentinformationBase.new_MotherName_lookup
    )
SELECT Customername,
       AccountName,
       FullName,
       MobilePhone,
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ParentPhone END) AS ParentPhone1,
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ParentPhone END) AS ParentPhone2,
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ParentPhone END) AS ParentPhone3,
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ParentPhone END) AS ParentPhone4,
       Language
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY Customername,
          AccountName,
          FullName,
          MobilePhone,
          Language
```

**Note :** If number of `ParentPhone` per `Name` is unknown then you need to use Dynamic pivot. Also start using alias name to make the query more readable

Comment: Dear Prdp, actually the number of ParentPhone per Name is unknown, and I Am not expert in advanced Microsoft Queriers , so can u help me to sort it out

Comment: Now its working fine thank you, but i cant save it, h got this message always: Warning: The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the TOP Clause in the View Definition. The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried, unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

Comment: How i can save this in my View, as i searched i got that Order by cant saved in the view so how i can use Query similar to your Query and saved under View.

Comment: Its working now after removing ; before with, thank u very much for your help